# Hibernate Mapping - How to Join Three Tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have 3 Entity: PERSON, CAR, and PROFFESION.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PERSON")
    public class Person implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<Car> cars;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<Profession> professions;
    }
```

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PROFESSION")
    public class Profession implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
        private Person person;
    }
```

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CAR")
    public class Car implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
        private Person person;
    }
```

When i'm trying to retrieve a person with connections to two professions and one car the result is two professions and two duplicated cars.

Or if he is connected to five cars and one profession, the result is five cars and five duplicated professions.

How should I correct the mappings so I receive the right results?

Comment: Simplest options. Remove eager fetch or change List<> to Set<>.

Comment: And how you retrieve a `Person`?

Comment: Thanks, I replaced List with Set and it worked. Yes, i use JPA.

Comment: @VakoBeridze It is interesting, that with `Hibernate` (not using `JPA`) you can't get `Person` with `List` at all, cause of `MultipleBagFetchException` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Set` to map oneToMany If you don't want duplicates. Its mapped with the `<set>` element in mapping table. so first you make changes to these parts:

```
private Set<Car> car = new HashSet<Car>(0);

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="persons")
    public Set<Car> getCar() {
        return this.car;
 }
public void setCar(Set<Car> car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
```

Do the same with profession and another oneToMany you do not want duplicates. you can set fetchType based on loading preferences. `Eager` load all at once and `Lazy` load on demand which is usually best.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced List with Set, and it worked. But I think this is solving the problem on code level. How would I fix it on the database level?

Comment: @VakoBeridze This duplicates because of the `left outer join` in the `SQL`. You can change this behaviour by using subselects (using `JPQL`), but, probably, you lost some performance.

Comment: @v.ladynev ok. thanks a lot.

Comment: @VakoBeridze You are welcome